# Refresh cache based on a database refresh

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis, caching

There are a bunch of web applications (asp.net, mvc and classic asp) running on IIS, that get their cache from a particular SQL server database table. When any row is updated in the table, some trigger mechanism should be set, so that it goes out and refreshes any cache that is affected by this data.

So in short, how do I refresh ASP.net cache as soon as the SQL table the cache is getting data from is refreshed?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear. Are you concerned with how to build the cache-structure, how to actually design and do it or the general discussion?

Comment: Anders, In essence what I am trying to do is, refresh ASP.net cache as soon as the SQL table the cache is getting data from is refreshed.

Comment: OK. From the wording of your question, it seems as if the central question is whether this would be a security issue. You might consider rephrasing, so that it is clear that you request help with the caching. :)

Comment: Anders, just edited my question. I hope its clearer now.

Comment: I think SqlCacheDependency Class is something that might help.

Comment: Yup. That's also included in the link in my answer below. I don't know if this matches your versions of IIS and SQL Server, but I hope it can get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlCacheDependency Class helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.sqlcachedependency.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done this myself - but you might want to take a look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3w8402y(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This link is broken ... opens a page "Visual Studio 2005 Retired documentation"